# How to implement Gmail Authentication Service in Asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I was just wondering if someone could give me a idea on how to implement Gmail OR Facebook OR yahoo Authentication Service in MVC 3...

need very basic - 2 textbox with 1 button and Jquery OR ajax code to implement that ...want to learn ...

1) what are the baisc steps do i need
2) what files do i need 
3) where to gather more information on this topic 
4) is there any example code out there on net?, so i can have a look and learn..
5) what are the best practice to have this kind of implementation...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Could look at a more general-purpose auth system, [like OAuth](http://oauth.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the DotNetAuth project : http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/